# Prevent opening page without login

Tags: php, html, authentication

I have created a webpage (lets call the root as main.php) and decided to put a login on top of it (file index.php). The login works fine, but the problem is this. If I type the address of the page (main.php) directly in the browser, it is opened.
Is there any way to prevent opening the page unless I go through the login?

In case it is relevant, this is the login code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">   
   </head>

   <body>
       <div class="login_container">
             <div id="login-form">
                <h3>Login</h3>
                <fieldset>
                    <form action="checklogin.php" method="post">
                            <input name="username" type="text" required placeholder="Username">
                                <input name="password" type="password" required placeholder="*******">
                                <input type="submit" value="Login">
                    </form>
                </fieldset>
            </div> 
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

and it directs to :

```
<?php

ob_start();

    // Define $username and $password 
    $username=$_POST['username']; 
    $password=$_POST['password']; 

    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $username = pg_escape_string($username);
    $password = pg_escape_string($password);

if($username == "username" && $password == "password"){
        $_SESSION['username']="username";
        $_SESSION['password']="password";
        header("location:main.php");
}
else header("location:index.php");
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: I dunno if there is any way to prevent opening the page unless you go through the login but you can still redirect people to the login page if they try to access the main.php without being logged in

Comment: very basic: `if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) { ... not logged on ...}` on every page you want protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check, on every request that requires a login, that the user is logged in and is authorized.

A good way of looking at this is seeing the request URL as part of the input to your program. Just like the cookies and GET/POST parameters are input.

`main.php` will either return a page with data or a request for login.

Comment: However, if I have many pages (main.php and other pages where I navigate from it) and I don't want any of them to be opened without a login, do I check in every single one of them if there was a login done?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. 
Check if the user is currently logged on when they access the page using php [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) if they aren't logged on send an error, or redirect them elsewhere.